# Applying filter for column using multi select dropdown with checkbox in datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables, bootstrap-multiselect

My question is based on this original fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x92c3qu2/

This is a kind of example I am looking for.
But my problem is when any value is having special characters (say, round brackets), then the example doesn't work.

This is my code - almost similar to original link

```
    $('#dropdown').multiselect({
    onChange: function(element, checked) {

      var cities = $('#dropdown option:selected');

      var selected = [];
      $(cities).each(function(index, city) {
        selected.push([$(this).val()]);
      });

      var regex = selected.join("|");

      $('#table').DataTable().column(1).search(
        regex, true, false, true
      ).draw();
    }
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x92c3qu2/110/  - **edited fiddle by me**

Now in this, if you select "**(Paris) France**", it does not show any result despite having record in a table.

(tried by changing search(regax,true,false,true) - but doesn't work.

If you select "**Paris**", it shows both records related to "**Paris**"- according to me which is wrong. It should show exact result when value selected from drop down.

Try selecting multiple values of with and without **special characters** - the result is weird.

Please let me know if any further clarifications required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the regex to match the exact string you have to encapsulate the search string with the `^` and the `$` characters. If the string has to match the exact string anyway you can disable the `smart` option in the `search` method.

There are two problems with the entry *(Paris) France*. In your sample you are pushing the value of the `option` element which is set to *Paris_France* but in your table the entry to look for is still *(Paris) France*, so you should change that. 
The second issue is that the `(` is a special character in Regex which you should escape in this case consider something like this when adding the value:

`selected.push(['^(' + $(this).val().replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') +')$']);`

I've edited your [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8unp1b92/2/) with my proposed changes.

Comment: Thank you Shiffty. Solved the problem. Cheers man..!!! The problem was, I couldn't apply proper Regex part. Thanks again.

Comment: One more thing. Provided solution works fine in chrome and mozilla. But, the same Regex DOES NOT work in IE 11 when there is **A SPACE BEFORE AND AFTER THE "DASH/HYPHEN"**. I am using IE 11, version 11.674.15063. I tried modifying Regex. Also tried using '\s'. But not worked in IE11. Can anyone please help ?

Comment: For example: ABCD - WXYZ (works in chrome), ABCD-WXYZ (works in chrome) . ABCD-WXYZ (works in IE11). **But**, ABCD - WXYZ (Does not work in IE11)

Comment: @The_Geek Consider asking a new question with a reproduceable example. Btw: I've tested it with IE 11 and it seems to work.